# how to use jquery .delay(1000) on the same element

Tags: jquery

I am trying the following but with no luck.

```
$("#mydiv").addClass('spin').delay(1000).$('#mydiv').removeClass('spin');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about a simple timeout instead:

```
$("#mydiv").addClass('spin');

setTimeout(function () {
    $("#mydiv").removeClass("spin");
}, 1000);
```

[Delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay) is designed to work with the effects queue, not to delay arbitrary statements. You can find a disclaimer to this end on the documentation page:

> The .delay() method is **best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects.** Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is **not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function**, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Answer (score 2):

the `delay` method isn't just a simple wait timer. You need to use a setTimeout call to do this.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: use `delay` for [Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) and setTimeout for everything else